# Wordpress Category Widget Drop-Down Slugs

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

How can I force the Category Widget (drop-down style) to link to the category slug instead of the ?cat=# ?

Comment: What is your category slug? Did you change *Category Base* to your category slug? Please clarify your question!

Comment: Any category.  Each one has it's own slug, and I have thousands of them.   By default the "Category Widget" display's all links to the categories linked via their respective slug.  When you change it to drop-down instead of list, all categories in the drop-down change to ?cat=# instead of the slug (/category/the_slug)

Comment: Did you change the [Permalink Settings](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)?

Comment: Yes, a few times.  I do %postname%, as it is needed for some of my pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do force display to override default wordpress category widget on our requirement. This is not best method to override default wordpress widgets. It will be best register new widget class and customize method. I think you can copy same widget class change name, variables, id to make same as default widget but different it will not affect default wordpress widgets. Below of override wordpress default category widget dropdown change display as your customization if this is helpful for you.

```
<?php 
/*
 * Plugin Name: Test
*/



add_action( 'widgets_init', 'plugin_prefix_widgets_init' );

function plugin_prefix_widgets_init(){

    register_widget( 'WP_Widget_Custom_Categories' );
}

if( ! class_exists( 'WP_Widget_Categories' ) )
include ABSPATH.'wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-categories.php';

class WP_Widget_Custom_Categories extends WP_Widget_Categories{



    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        // Apply conditinal tag to sepicific template only. Any other display to remove override widget display.
        /*if( ! is_page('page_slug') ){
          parent::widget( $args, $instance );
          return;   
        }*/


        static $first_dropdown = true;

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? __( 'Categories' ) : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );

        $c = ! empty( $instance['count'] ) ? '1' : '0';
        $h = ! empty( $instance['hierarchical'] ) ? '1' : '0';
        $d = ! empty( $instance['dropdown'] ) ? '1' : '0';

        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( $title ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        }

        $cat_args = array(
            'orderby'      => 'name',
            'show_count'   => $c,
            'hierarchical' => $h
        );

        if ( $d ) {
            $dropdown_id = ( $first_dropdown ) ? 'cat' : "{$this->id_base}-dropdown-{$this->number}";
            $first_dropdown = false;

            echo '<label class="screen-reader-text" for="' . esc_attr( $dropdown_id ) . '">' . $title . '</label>';

            $cat_args['show_option_none'] = __( 'Select Category' );
            $cat_args['id'] = $dropdown_id;
            $cat_args['value_field'] = 'slug';

            if( is_category() )
            $cat_args['selected'] = get_term( get_query_var('cat'), 'category' )->slug ;

            /**
             * Filter the arguments for the Categories widget drop-down.
             *
             * @since 2.8.0
             *
             * @see wp_dropdown_categories()
             *
             * @param array $cat_args An array of Categories widget drop-down arguments.
             */
            wp_dropdown_categories( apply_filters( 'widget_categories_dropdown_args', $cat_args ) );
            ?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById( "<?php echo esc_js( $dropdown_id ); ?>" );
    function onCatChange() {
        if ( dropdown.options[ dropdown.selectedIndex ].value != -1 ) {
            location.href = "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/category/"+dropdown.options[ dropdown.selectedIndex ].value;
        }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
})();
/* ]]> */
</script>

<?php
        } else {
?>
        <ul>
<?php
        $cat_args['title_li'] = '';

        /**
         * Filter the arguments for the Categories widget.
         *
         * @since 2.8.0
         *
         * @param array $cat_args An array of Categories widget options.
         */
        wp_list_categories( apply_filters( 'widget_categories_args', $cat_args ) );
?>
        </ul>
<?php
        }

        echo $args['after_widget'];

    }

    // Only need to change customize widget method to display as requirement
}
```

Sorry for poor english.

Answer (score 2):

I have found this on wordpress forums. Its pretty old post but resolves your issue.
[cat slug in dropdown wp forums](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/i-need-to-get-the-category-slug-from-the-category-id)

```
<?php

function replace_id_for_slug($option){
$categories = get_categories("hide_empty=0");

preg_match('/value="(\d*)"/', $option[0], $matches);

$id = $matches[1];

$slug = "";

foreach($categories as $category){
    if($category->cat_ID == $id){
        $slug = $category->slug;
    }
}

return preg_replace("/value=\"(\d*)\"/", "value=\"$slug\"", $option[0]);
}

$select = wp_dropdown_categories("hierarchical=1&hide_empty=0&echo=0");

$select = preg_replace_callback("#<option[^>]*>[^<]*</option>#", "replace_id_for_slug", $select);

echo $select;

?>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
function onCatChange() {
    if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value != -1 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');?>/"+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value+"/";
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
--></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not against an additional plugin, there is also this option since the other answers are breaking down your code.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/extended-categories-widget/